# Log request string URL with # (number sign, hash, fragment) to apache/httpd custom access log?

Tags: apache, logging, httprequest, special-characters, uri-fragment

In a [Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) I use [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) and [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) to log [HTTP Requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html):

```
LogFormat "\"%r\"" custom
```

The problem is that the entire [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) isn't being logged when there's a [`#`(Number Sign)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) in the URL (Visiting `domain.tld/slug/foo^bar#baz` results in `"GET /slug/foo%5ebar HTTP/1.1"` in which `#baz` is omitted).

Is there any reason why a `#` character in the URL only gets logged until that point in the string? Is there documentation available on this or a way to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fragment part of the URL (the part after '#') is never sent to the server: it remains entirely client-side.

Comment: That appears to be true. I've used `tcpdump` to dump the request that my browser made and everything until the `#` gets sent along.